# Arxiv API not taking the whole query terms

Tags: python

I am using **arxiv API** for scholarly papers search using python. For single term query arxiv API working perfectly well but for multi-term query (Key-phrase), API only took first term.

For example :

```
 import urllib.request as ur
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 url = 'http://export.arxiv.org/api/query?search_query=all:electron'
 s = ur.urlopen(url)
 sl = s.read()
 soup = BeautifulSoup(sl, 'html.parser')
 papers=[soup.find_all('title')]
 print(soup)
```

Output(print the soup variable)

[image]

Here I used query term **electron**, Arxiv API search also electron term (highlighted).

But I used query term say **quantum complexity of a black hole**, arxiv API only took the first word (quantum).

```
import urllib.request as ur
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://export.arxiv.org/api/query?search_query=all:quantum complexity of a black hole'
#url='http://export.arxiv.org/api/query?search_query=ti:"quantum complexity of a black hole"&sortBy=lastUpdatedDate&sortOrder=ascending'
s = ur.urlopen(url)
sl = s.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(sl, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

Output: 
[image]

How can I search using whole key-words (quantum complexity of a black hole) so that it will return the scholarly papers that contain those key-words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to encode your query params

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request as ur
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
query = urllib.parse.quote("all:quantum complexity of a black holeu")
url = 'http://export.arxiv.org/api/query?search_query=' + query
s = ur.urlopen(url)
sl = s.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(sl, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```